# edmx and designer.cs are not in sync

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I updated my DB and updated that table in edmx. (deleted the table and did "Update Model From Database") I see the current table representation in edmx, however my Designer.cs file contains the old entity (representation of that table). Is there a way to regenerate the Designer.cs based on the edmx?

Thanks

Comment: Which designer file are you referring to? Did you run the template? (Right click .tt file and click "run custom tool"). This is usually done automatically for the context when you save the edmx after changes, but if you have separate POCO entities then you need to manually re-run that template.

Comment: I'm talking about the auto generated from edmx, Model.Designer.cs file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

1. I fixed it by removing the updated table from the edmx.
2. Rebuilding the project.
3. Adding the table again and rebuilding afterwards.

At first I did not do the rebuild in step 2 and the designer.cs did not get updated.